# split an audio into smaller 5 seconds chunks but error of tuple index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, audio, tuples, chunks

I want to split an audio into smaller 5 seconds chunks

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
from pydub import AudioSegment
import IPython.display as ipd
import soundfile as sf
from pydub.silence import split_on_silence

filename= "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/22__19_07_13_adventure_maniobra.wav"
y,sr = librosa.load(filename, sr=None)
for i in range(0, len(filename), 5 * sr):
  u = filename[5 * sr * i: 5 * sr *(i+1)]
  sf.write("dest_audio"+str(i)+".wav", u, sr)
```

I am following the code of
https://groups.google.com/g/librosa/c/6UE47GMz0aM
but getting the error in the `sf.write` function:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-ca78240adb01> in <cell line: 9>()
      9 for i in range(0, len(filename),5 * sr):
     10   u = filename[5 * sr * i: 5 * sr *(i+1)]
---> 11   sf.write("dest_audio"+str(i)+".wav", u, sr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/soundfile.py in write(file, data, samplerate, subtype, endian, format, closefd)
    340         channels = 1
    341     else:
--> 342         channels = data.shape[1]
    343     with SoundFile(file, 'w', samplerate, channels,
    344                    subtype, endian, format, closefd) as f:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: have you tried using ffmpeg ?

Comment: no, kindly guide me how?